# Let an analytic function $f$ have domain-set the punctured disk $\Delta^*(z_0,r)$. Assume the existence of a complex number $w_0$ and a sequence

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

**Let an analytic function $f$ have domain-set the punctured disk $\Delta^*(z_0,r)$. Assume the existence of a complex number $w_0$ and a sequence $\{r_n\}$ of positive real numbers satisfying $r>r_1>r_2>...>r_n\rightarrow 0$ concerning which it is true that $M_n=max\{|f(z)-w_0|:z\in K(z_0,r_n)\}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Demonstrate that $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}f(z)=w_0$. Conclude that by defining $f(z_0)=w_0$ we can extend $f$ to be a function that is analytic in the full disk $\Delta(z_0,r)$.**

As $M_n=max\{|f(z)-w_0|:z\in K(z_0,r_n)\}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ then, given $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\geq N$ then $|M_n|<\epsilon$, then $|f(z)-w_0|<\epsilon$ if $z\in K(z_0,r_{N+1})$ with which if $|z-z_0|<r_{N+1} := \delta$ then $|f(z)-w_0|<\epsilon$, and so $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}f(z)=w_0$. Is this reasoning correct? Could someone please help me explain the second part of the exercise that I do not understand very well? Thank you very much.